# Can you have a potion of Inflict Serious Wounds?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, potions, injury

Can you create a potion of Inflict Serious (etc.) Wounds?

If so, does it give you the ability to do a touch attack which does the Inflict, or does it Inflict the wounds on the drinker?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Yes; it damages the drinker.

The rules on potions, from the SRD:

> It can duplicate the effect of a spell of up to 3rd level that has a casting time of less than 1 minute.
>
> Potions are like spells cast upon the imbiber.

And under Creating Potions:

> The imbiber of the potion is both the caster and the target. Spells with a range of personal cannot be made into potions.

There's no rule that potions have to be beneficial to you.

In fact, a few D&D 3e sourcebooks feature potions of inflict light/moderate/serious wounds, mainly as they heal undead. The psychic vampire Kantos from the Libris Mortis web enhancement *Tarus's Banquet* carries a potion of *inflict moderate wounds*, as does the phantom ghast ninja Kugan from *Monster Manual V*.